# update several users with one request

Tags: soap-api

I need to update all users that share the same accountid by soap requests.

1) Is it possible to update an user by providing any other field than his Id?
2) Is it possible to update several users based on a common field value, in my case the accountid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `upsert` and reference a User field that has been marked as "External ID". The only two choices you have are to reference by ID or reference by External ID. To update multiple users based on some Account ID, which probably won't be unique (e.g. partner portal users, etc), you'll have to query the records, then update them. Without a query, there's no way to simply update those records.